# Populating an RSS feed with our database content?

Tags: asp-classic, rss

I have a question about creation of an RSS feed.
I have read a few different bits of information on creation of an RSS feed and this, on the whole doesn't appear too difficult.

What I'm struggling to understand though is how to automatically populate the RSS feed xml file?

Here is our basic .xml file...

`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>`

`<rss version='2.0'>`

`<channel>`

`<title>Channel Title</title>`

`<description>Description of Channel</description>`

`<link>http://www.test.com</link>`

`<item>`

`<title>Item Title</title>`

`<description>Updated on: 5/20/2012</description>`

`<link>http://www.test.com/itempage.asp?itemID=1</link>`

`</item>`

`</channel>`

`</rss>`

We can, obviously, manually enter each item but I want this to automatically select the latest items from our database.  In this case, news items.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0 object. have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms764730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for MSXML DOM Reference.

with that object you can create xml nodes and then save the xml document...

example:

```
set xml = server.createobject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
set rssNode = xml.createElement("rss")
rssNode.appendChild(xml.createTextNode(""))
rssNode.setAttribute "version", "2.0"
```